# Включение функций из заголовка с помощью define

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Файл `a.h`

```
#pragma once

#define _A_DEF

#include "b.h"

class A { }; // А класс
```

Файл `b.h`

```
#pragma once

#define _B_DEF

#ifdef _A_DEF
#define _PROV_A_DEF
#endif

class B { }; // B класс
```

`_A_DEF` и `_B_DEF` "флаги" заголовков `a.h` и `b.h`, соответственно
Флаг `_A_DEF` сообщает `b.h` что нужно "включить" объявление нескольких функций, и также их определения в `b.cp`p (`a.h` содержит и объявления и определения своих функций в себе, временно, то есть у него нет `a.cpp`).

```
class B
{
#ifdef _PROV_A_DEF
friend class A; // видит класс
#endif
    ....
#ifdef _PROV_A_DEF
protected:
        void ex1(....);
        bool ex2(....);
#endif
};
```

Все сделано для того, чтобы из класса А пользоваться функциями из класса В. В файле b.cpp точно также через директивы `#ifdef #endif` определенны функции `ex1` и `ex2`
Однако, это все не линкуется (компилируется если не использовать в классе А "нужные" функции из класса `В`). Выходит ошибка: ссылка на неразрешенный символ.

**Как можно провернуть все это(объявить и определить их в зависимости от наличия флага из файла `a.h`)?**

P.S.
Макрос `_PROV_A_DEF` определен дополнительно и возможно излишне, так как с `_A_DEF` не получалось(решил что `b.cpp` не видит `_A_DEF`, а `b.h` видит).
Также, "отключение" `pragma once` в `b.h` не решает проблему

Пример желаемой работы:
b.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define _B_DEF

#ifdef _A_DEF
#define _PROV_A_DEF
#endif

class B
{
#ifdef _PROV_A_DEF
friend class A; // видит класс
#endif
    B () {}

    void ex1(::std::vector<int>);
    bool ex2(int);
#ifdef _PROV_A_DEF
protected:
    void ex1(::std::vector<int>, int);
    bool ex2(int, int);
#endif
};
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

void B::ex1(::std::vector<int> vint)
{
    ::std::cout << vint.size() << ::std::endl;
}

bool B::ex2(int x)
{
    return x == 12;
}

#ifdef _PROV_A_DEF
void B::ex1(::std::vector<int> vint, int x)
{
    ::std::cout << vint.size() + x << ::std::endl;
}

bool B::ex2(int x, int num)
{
    return x == num;
}
#endif
```

a.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#define _A_DEF

#include "b.h"

class A
{
public:
    B test;

    A () {}

private:
    void somefunc()
    {
        test.ex1(::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}, 4); // вызов перегруженной функции
        bool res = test.ex2(4, 4);           // вызов перегруженной функции
    }
};
```

В main.cpp

```
#include "a.h" // подключен b.h с доп. функциями

int main()
{
    A testa;
    testa.somefunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Если бы я не хотел добавлять в проект "надстройку", то main выглядел бы так

```
#include "b.h" // подключен b.h без доп. функций

int main()
{
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не пойму вашу сверхзадачу... Не хотите ли вы сказать, что у вас могут быть разные определения класса `B` в зависимости от того, какой файл компилируется? или я неверно понял?

Comment: @Harry, Есть header1 и его единственное определение в cpp файле. Я хочу "надстроить" над ним header2, который будет пользоваться его функциями. Но, вот не задача, потребовалось дополнить header1 некоторыми функциями(все это только для использования в header2). Однако не хочется вносить их "на совсем" в header1, а только по случаю, когда есть та самая надстройка в виде header2.

Comment: @dreamIIx, лучше приведите пример использования, как если бы то, что вы хотите работало. Просто лично я тоже ничего не понял.

Comment: @eanmos, я крайне надеюсь что пример понятен, к сожалению большой. Вся суть вопроса - как сделать чтобы макросы в a.h были видны в b.h и b.cpp

Comment: @dreamIIx,  тут дело в том, что все `.cpp` компилируются отдельно, т. е. образуют единицу трансляции. А директивы `#include` буквально вставляют содержимое некоторого файла в тот где они встречаются. Поэтому единственный способ сделать макрос `A_DEF` видимым в `b.cpp` — это подключить к `b.cpp` файл `a.h`, что, конечно, неприемлемо. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что можно как-то извратиться с макросами, чтобы это работало. Обычно для добавления «надстроек» просто используют `#ifdef` и ко. Т. е. в вашем случае нужно просто удалить `a.h`, а в `main.cpp` перед включением `b.h` добавить `#define A_DEF`.

Comment: @eanmos, вы писали: "тут дело в том, что все .cpp компилируются отдельно, т. е. образуют единицу трансляции". Именно поэтому я и определил дополнительный макрос `_PROV_A_DEF`, считая что это при включении b.h в b.cpp, последний увидит определенный в заголовке макрос.

Comment: @dreamIIx, если в `b.cpp` видно `_PROV_A_DEF`, то в нем видно и `_A_DEF`, так что первый — излишен.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо Вам за ранее развернутый комментарий, он поспособствовал решению.

Comment: @dreamIIx, не за что :) А вообще решение не очень хорошее — могут возникнуть проблемы с ODR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом.
Так как проблема была именно в линковке `b.cpp`(файл `b.cpp` не видел макросов), я перетащил определения "дополнительных" функций в `a.h`(временно там находятся и объявления и определения, то есть с `a.cpp` не пробовал).
Все остальное осталось на своих местах, флаги файлов `a.h` и `b.h` в самих заголовках, а объявления "дополнительных" функций в `b.h` так же остались завернуты в `#ifdef` и `#endif`.